# Windows 2000 Pro SP4 Repair

Tags: windows, bsod, windows-2000

I have a Windows 2000 Pro SP4 that is giving the BSOD screen.
I am using the windows repair function to try to repair the hard disk.
After booting from the "Windows 2000 PRO SP4' CD
and going to the repair function is asks to insert the:
"Service Pack 4 CD"

Anyone has any idea what this CD is & steps on how to prepare one ?

I burned the W2KSP4.EXE after expanding with the /x option to a temp directory
to a CD and inserted it, but it did not accept it.